# Delete entire list if lambda condition is met

Tags: python, lambda

Suppose you have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],['a',12,3,4,5,], ['a',123,4,5,6]]
```

Can I delete (using `lambda`) the the lists that have `a` in their first element? 
I'm starting to play with Python's lambda and this has been something that's been puzzling me for a while.  Can it be done?

Comment: Sure it can be done, but why would you use it with lambda and not just list comprehension (other than just learning lambdas). Also show your attempts please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` removes the elements from the given list for which the given function returns `False`. List comprehensions can be used with a predicate similarly.

```
>>> xss = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],['a',12,3,4,5,], ['a',123,4,5,6]]
>>> list(filter(lambda xs: len(xs) != 0 and xs[0] != 'a', xss))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> [xs for xs in xss if len(xs) != 0 and xs[0] != 'a']
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Correct answer!!

Answer (score 0):

@rightfold is right, though if you want to make it generic for a list with 'a' in any position:

```
>>>test_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], ['a', 12, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 123, 4, 5, 6]]
>>>filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and 'a' not in x, test_list)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>>[x for x in test_list if len(x) > 0 and 'a' not in x]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter(lambda i: i if i[0] != 'a' else False, [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],['a',12,3,4,5,], ['a',123,4,5,6]])`